# d3.js: linking related items

Tags: d3.js, relationship

I'm trying to create a graph with d3.js that shows relationships or links between items.

the basic idea is this:
[image]

when I hover or click on one of the items, the related items highlight

I've looked at d3.layout.tree https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout but it seems different from what I'm trying to do.

I saw this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmdhacks/qsEbd/5/
which seemed like it might be a start in the right direction

Based on that fiddle, I built this fiddle with my own data set
http://jsfiddle.net/Ps4Fe/1/
and at first it looked like it would work. But then I realized that I was getting circles overlaid on other circles, and multiple copies... and I see why.

There may be a problem in the way I built the data. That can be changed.

```
    var data = {
    "Product": [
        {
            "type": "product",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "links": [
                {
                    "name": "Industry 1",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.12,
                    "count": 149
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 2",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.18,
                    "count": 180
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 3",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.17,
                    "count": 152
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 4",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.16,
                    "count": 175
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 5",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.25,
                    "count": 21
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size A",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.24,
                    "count": 21
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size B",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.15,
                    "count": 49
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size C",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.15,
                    "count": 83
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size D",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.17,
                    "count": 128
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size E",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.13,
                    "count": 241
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size F",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.08,
                    "count": 161
                }            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "links": [
                {
                    "name": "Industry 1",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.06,
                    "count": 15
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 3",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.21,
                    "count": 52
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 5",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.15,
                    "count": 39
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size C",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.28,
                    "count": 78
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size D",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.13,
                    "count": 73
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "name": "Product 3",
            "links": [
                {
                    "name": "Industry 4",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.18,
                    "count": 15
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 5",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.19,
                    "count": 52
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size A",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.15,
                    "count": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size D",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.18,
                    "count": 55
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size E",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.14,
                    "count": 47
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size F",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.13,
                    "count": 24
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "name": "Product 4",
            "links": [
                {
                    "name": "Industry 2",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.1,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 3",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.01,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size A",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.21,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size B",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.11,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size C",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.18,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size D",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.14,
                    "count": null
                }            
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "product",
            "name": "Product 5",
            "links": [
                {
                    "name": "Industry 1",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.1,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 2",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.15,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 3",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.03,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Industry 4",
                    "type": "industry",
                    "percent": 0.08,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size 2",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.08,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size 3",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.18,
                    "count": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Size 5",
                    "type": "size",
                    "percent": 0.25,
                    "count": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Industry": [
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Agriculture, Forestry & Fishery"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Arts & Entertainment"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Construction"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Educational Services"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Finance & Insurance"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Health Care & Social Assistance"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Manufacturing"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Mining"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Professional Services"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Public Administration"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Real Estate"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Retail Trade"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Services - Other"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Technology & Communication"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Transportation & Warehousing"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Utilities"
        },
        {
            "type": "industry",
            "name": "Wholesale Trade"
        }
    ],
    "Size": [
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size A"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size B"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size C"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size D"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size E"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size F"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size G"
        },
        {
            "type": "size",
            "name": "Size H"
        }
    ]
};
```

My thought was that I could match up the 'links' under each Product type with the matching Size or Industry types.

My javascript is here:

```
var width = 600,
    height = 600,
    margin = {top: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16, left: 16},
    radius = 10, 
    gap = 24;

var dProduct = data.Product;

// test layout
var nodes = [];
var links = [];
dProduct.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.x = width/2;
    d.y = margin.top + gap*i;
    nodes.push(d);
    d.links.forEach(function(c, i) {
        if(c.type === 'industry'){
            c.x = margin.left;
            c.y = margin.top + gap * (i+1) -2*radius;
        }else if (c.type === 'size'){
            c.x = width-margin.right-radius*2;
            c.y = margin.top + gap * (i+1) -2*radius;
        }
        nodes.push(c);

        var a = {x:c.y, y:c.x};
        var b = {x:d.y, y:d.x};
        links.push({source: b, target: a});
    });
});

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

var circle = svg.selectAll(".circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "circle");

var el = circle.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x})
        .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y})
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.name)})
        .append("title").text(function(d) {return d.name});
```

The main problem, I think is that I'm essentially creating the Size and Industry nodes from the links, rather than creating the full set of nodes and then linking them.

**How can I layout the 3 types (Industry, Product, Size), and then create the links between the Products and the other two types? Or more precisely, how do I create the links after I layout the 3 types?**

Thanks!

Comment: Any solution found? Will be glad if you can share.

Comment: Sorry @Fr0zenFyr, I didn't solve this one. I will probably be returning to it in a couple months, and will try again.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm also working on something that is almost exact thing in your question. I will post an answer if I find a solution before you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you're saying that your problem is that you are getting multiple copies of nodes, this should be easily solved by ensuring that nodes only get added to the `nodes` array once.      One way to ensure uniqueness is to use an associative array like `d3.map`:

```
var nodeMap = d3.map();
var links = [];
dProduct.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.x = width/2;
    d.y = margin.top + gap*i;
    nodeMap.set(d.name, d);
    d.links.forEach(function(c, i) {
        if(c.type === 'industry'){
            c.x = margin.left;
            c.y = margin.top + gap * (i+1) -2*radius;
        }else if (c.type === 'size'){
            c.x = width-margin.right-radius*2;
            c.y = margin.top + gap * (i+1) -2*radius;
        }
        nodeMap.set(c.name, c);

        var a = {x:c.y, y:c.x};
        var b = {x:d.y, y:d.x};
        links.push({source: b, target: a});
    });
});

var nodes = nodeMap.values();
```

Note the only change to this code from what you had is the use of `nodeMap` instead of `nodes` in the loops and then the `nodeMap.values()` call at the end.

After this, `nodes` should be an array of unique nodes that you can use to create the circles and `links` should still contain all the same information as before to link everything up.

Comment: Thanks Scott! After spending some time reading last night, I thought the answer probably involved .map(), but wasn't really sure how. I actually revised my data set last night so that I have nodes and links, and each node has a unique id, and each link has a source and target key. But using your example and the old data, your example eliminates the duplicate nodes, but it has paths to nowhere: http://jsfiddle.net/gdTae/1/  getting closer!